# Multiples of 2 numbers that differ by 1

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have 2 known positive integers, $a$ and $b$ . Is there a *' standard '* formula to find the lowest (if possible) positive integers $x$ and $y$ , so that the following is true?

> $$xa = yb + 1$$

Comment: Have you seen Bezout's Lemma?

Comment: Are you familiar with modular arithmetic and congruency ?

Comment: Look up the 'Euclidean algorithm'

Comment: Take $a=2$ and $b=4$. Then there are no such integers $x,y$, because $xy-yb$ is even. For coprime $a$ and $b$ just use Bezout's Lemma.

Comment: Integers $x,y$ can be found iff $\gcd(a,b)=1$. Since in at least some cases one of $x,y$ may be negative, it is not clear what you mean by making $x,y$ the lowest. One possibility is $|xy|$ is minimized.

Comment: I only know that `b` will always be prime. And it doesn't necessarily need to be the 'lowest' answer, I just need _a_ answer. Thanks for the response by the way!

Comment: @DanDeg So what you seek is the inverse of $\,a\,$ modulo a prime $\,p,\,$ for which there are various well known algorithms - see the linked dupes.